# How to create simple pasword srcipt ?

Tags: html

I want to create website which is protected with password. For example: If you type correct password then you can go to website index page. Another important thing that script should always send notification to my email when user types password and click login button.

Thanks fot help.

Comment: have you tried creating a website using ASP.NET? even php can do this. you just need to know how to code in these languages

Comment: What is the Web server?

Answer (score 0):

there is quite a lot of stuff you need for that:

-a database (so you need to know how to use phpmyadmin)

-SQL (the language to access the database)

-php (a language to use SQL commands from your website)
and you need to learn about php Session variables which are individual for each user and in which you store the mail or username when a user successfully identified himself.

You should google this stuff and also I found this tutorial very helpful when designing my first site:
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-build-a-login-system-for-a-simple-website--net-2853